# Can we retrieve data from database in this format?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can we retrieve data from database in this format in node.js ?

```
'{
     SchoolCode: 1,
    [{
     LABName: 'Physics',
     Category :[{
        SubCategory: 'Internal',
         Questions:[{
            QuestionNumber: 1,
            QuestionText: ?????????,
         },{
            QuestionNumber: 2,
            QuestionText: ?????????,
         }]
     }]
}'
```

Comment: it will not print in this format. I want to print that object in this format and in JSON format only

Comment: `JSON.stringify(object)`

Comment: I have tried this Michelem. Again saying this will not give o/p as in this format

Comment: Ok if you know to format in this format please tell. @torazaburo